# Wifi Problem Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Ok, I am a new linux user as of 30 mins ago and it won't let me connect to any wireless network. How can I fix this in the simplest terms? haha

Thanks

```
nathan@nathan-eMachines-E725:~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
nathan@nathan-eMachines-E725:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nathan: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
nathan@nathan-eMachines-E725:~$ sudo update-pciids
Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2015-03-29 03:15:02
nathan@nathan-eMachines-E725:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
nathan@nathan-eMachines-E725:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good to see new newbe on Ubuntu ;)

I'm not good at english nor pro on Ubuntu, but i'm quite sure You'll need to provide more information. Start from:

1. run terminal (icon usually looks like black box with '>_' text in it
2. type lspci
3. copy output and paste it here

You propably work on laptop, so you can tell us what is the model name.

If You can, please connect Your pc via wire and try to install propietary drivers.
While waiting for the answer, follow this tuto: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers

Comment: Try it now, your English sounds fine

Comment: here You go: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
btw. something is blocking apt, thats why You get 'Could not get lock' message - close Synaptic or any other package manager.

Comment: The only things that are running are firefox and terminal

Comment: You can reboot Your PC - it'll be faster ;).
Anyway, You still might need networking...

Comment: @ Nathan O, if you are sure Software Updater is not open try `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and see if `sudo apt-get update` will work